# unknown command now that chrome has updated when using Watir-webdriver

Tags: selenium, rake, watir-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Last week chrome auto updated to 29.0.1547.57 and they completely messed up all of our regression tests. So I downloaded and updated my chromedriver to v2.2. Now the test will at least run but almost all fail with this error.

```
unexpected response, code=404, content-type="text/plain"
  unknown command: session/f82f867596e3c001854423097f341bfe/element/name (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError)
```

The real confusing part is that it works on my local when I start the test through rubymine, but when the test run on the server started by Jenkins they all fail.

They seem to be failing on wait_until_present when we wait for our ajax popups to load, and also on .exists?. For example:

```
if @browser.a(:id, 'hn_modal_close').exists?
  @browser.a(:class, 'blackText noTextDecoration').click
else
  @browser.link(:href, /shopping_cart.cfm/).click
end
```

It errors on the first line of the if statement, but this exact code works fine if I run it with irb.

EDIT

Found out that the reason it passes on my local and irb is because the error only comes when starting the test by rake. Jenkins started the test by executing the rake file.

So this seems to be a rake problem with the newest chromedriver im guess as it worked prior to upgrading. Question is still out there though as to fix this problem?

Does anybody have any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but a 'bundle update' solved it for me. There was a newer version of watir and selenium webdrivers, I think that did the trick. Give it a try if you haven't done so yet.